# How to push_back an object in a vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I'm coding a program using binary tree, I need to add a node as a son, so I used a struct. So I'm trying to add the child by looking for the adresse of his father, I keep getting an error that there is no know conversion

```
struct PERSON {
  string name;
  vector<PERSON> childs;
  PERSON *father;
};

typedef PERSON *Tree;

PERSON * searchPerson(Tree p, string name){
for(int i=0; i <= p->childs.size(); i++){
    if(p->childs[i].name == name){
        return p;
        break;
    }
}
  return nullptr;
}

void add(Tree p, string nameChild, string nameFa){
  PERSON *newPerson = new PERSON;
  PERSON *father = searchPerson(p, nameFa); // its actually a function that return the adresse of the person

  newPerson->name = nameChild;
  newPerson->father = father;

  father->childs.push_back(newPerson);
}

int main(){
  Tree r = nullptr;

  PERSON *p = searchPerson(r, "Test");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, I suspect you meant to do father->childs.push_back(...) in the final line.

Comment: true, its a mistake, thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  The provided code won't compile.

Comment: @StephenNewell done, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is new? `new` is a reserved C++ keyword. You can't pass it to a function.

```cpp
 father->childs.push_back(new);
```

Rather you want to call this:

```cpp
 father->childs.push_back(*newPerson);
```

Also, avoid using normal pointers to manage memory allocation. Use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) which deallocates memory upon destruction.

Comment: its just a mistake cause i did translate the code in english so u guys can understand, and thank you i actually forgot the * so my code wasnt compiling. I'm gonna take a look for myself, because it's a homework and i need to do it by the way i lean it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good luck. Always provide code when asking on SO. **A Code is worth a million words**.